# Skip age checks for html parsing

Tags: android

I'm using something like this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)); String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
 str.append(line);
}
```

to get the source code of particular website. My problem is that some pages have age checking, is there anyway to bypass this? or inject javascript code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a form in the HTML :

```
 <form action="http://store.steampowered.com/agecheck/app/72850/" method="post" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
```

you have to do an HttpPost request to the URL `http://store.steampowered.com/agecheck/app/72850/`

You have to provide all necessary values for the following input fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="snr" value="1_agecheck_agecheck__age-gate">
<select name="ageDay">
<select name="ageMonth">
<select name="ageYear">
```

Then you will get the HTML of the main page.

Comment: One of the website is Steam, and in this case there is no link to the mainpage and the information isn't there either.

Comment: Could you post the HTML of the age checker?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CehTay62 for the store.steampowered.com/agecheck/app/72850/ page

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the age checks with Java's [HTMLunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) which creates a 'GUI-less browser object' and lets your connection act as a browser (your code is in Java right?).

HTMLunit is similar to Perl's WWW::Mechanize library.